# Variable is not incrementing with the function I have written

Tags: javascript, dom, foreach, increment

I am fairly new to Javascript and am trying to create a quiz.  I am having issues getting the finalScore variable to increment when an answer is correct.  I have been trying to figure this out for the last two hours!

When I go into console log, it just says incorrect every time, even when clicking on the right answer, it just doesn't seem to be registering the clicks at all.

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

These are the things I've tried:

I originally had chosenAnswer as a variable inside the decideIfCorrectIncrementScore function but changed it to how it is now after reading something on here - don't know if that actually made any kind of difference to be honest!  It seemed like neater code.

I tried using .textContent on the variables in the decideIfCorrectIncrementScore function, again after reading something on here. I thought maybe this would get it to recognise the response. This didn't make a difference though.

This is my HTML for the quiz pages - they are all the same apart from the questions/answers:

```
  <body class="bg">
    <div class="container-fluid central-header-quiz-page">
      <p>What has more calories?</p>

      <div class="row row-no-margin">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-xl-4">
          <i class="fa-regular fa-circle choices icon-background2"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-xl-3">
          <p class="quiz-text correc">Blueberry Muffin</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-xl-4">
          <i class="fa-regular fa-circle choices correct-answer"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-xl-3">
          <p class="quiz-text">Cupcake</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row row-no-margin">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-xl-4">
          <i class="fa-regular fa-circle choices"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-xl-3">
          <p class="quiz-text">Granola bar</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div>
      <!-- Button code from Bootstrap - DO I NEED TO ADD - onlick = "goToNextPage()" - to make the js code functional here? See https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-create-a-link-in-javascript/ -->
      <a href="quiz-page-2.html">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-md" id="quiz-next-page">
        Go to next page
      </button>
    </a>
  </div>
    </div>

    <script src="assets/js/script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And this is my JS code:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  console.log("DOM fully loaded and parsed");
});

let finalScore = 0;
let chosenAnswer;

/** Function that reacts when the user chooses an answer */
function chooseAnAnswer() {
  let choices = document.querySelectorAll(".choices");

  choices.forEach((choice) => {
    choice.addEventListener("click", function () {
      choices.forEach((otherChoice) => {
        otherChoice.classList.remove("chosen");
      });
      choice.classList.add("chosen");
      chosenAnswer = choice;
    });
  });

}

chooseAnAnswer();

/** Function that decides which is the correct answer and increments the final score */
function decideIfCorrectIncrementScore() {
  let correctAnswer = document.querySelector(".correct-answer");

  if (chosenAnswer == correctAnswer) {
    finalScore++;
    console.log("Correct!");
  } else {
    console.log("Incorrect!");
  }
}

/** Function that takes use to next page and calls decideIfCorrect function */
function goToNextPage() {
  document.addEventListener("click", function () {
    decideIfCorrectIncrementScore();
    document.getElementById("quiz-next-page").style.backgroundColor = "#FA5F22";
  });
}

/** Function that shows the user their score */
function showScore() {
  
  if (finalScore <= 4) {
    document.getElementById("score-text").innerHTML = "Oh dear you only scored " + finalScore
  } else if (finalScore >= 5){
    document.getElementById("score-text").innerHTML = "Yay! You scored " + finalScore;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("score-text").innerHTML = "Oh dear, there has been an error."
  };
};
```

In case it's needed, this is the code for the score-page (minus the Head)

```
<body onload="showScore()" class="bg">
    <div class="container-fluid central-header">
      <h2 id="score-text">"You scored..."</h2>
    
    <a href="quiz-page-template.html">
      <!-- Button code from Bootstrap -->
      <button a type="button" class="btn btn-light btn-lg">Try again</button>
    </a>
    </div
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: there is one fundamental flaw in your script: the state is not shared between different pages so any variable set on the first page won't be visible on the second page. You would need to save it somehow like using the sessionStorage. Anyway in your case, can you just keep the logic in a single place, showing each question one by one without loading another page?

Comment: another trick could be passing the counter of correct questions given so far in a GET parameter by adding it to the url you are visiting for the next page (there are several ways to achieve it.. even using a whole form wrapping the link acting like a submit button or just appending the value in the url to visit like `url?param=value`)

Comment: *HTML for the quiz pages*  - Javascript works like the a new notebook.  You open a page, it's blank (has no javascript variable values etc) - you then write on page (add/change variables).  When you press F5 (or other way to refresh the page or load a new page), it's the same as turning the page in the notebook - you now have an new, empty page with no javascript values and have to start again.   The notebook is your site.   The "total" isn't remembered across each page, every time the browser opens a new page, there's no javascript data on that page and it has not be set or loaded.

Comment: Ok this is information I didn't know! Thanks very much.  Going to look into saving the information in the variables between the pages.